# Translate into notation of predicate logic with Domain

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

How can I translate the following statement into Predicate logic and what will be the domain? Basically I know how to find domain and predicate logic.

Example: `All americans eat cheese burger`

for this, First domain will be 
`Americans` and logic will be `A(x)`:x eat cheese burger. So, ∀x L(x). Second domain will be `people in america` and logic will be `P(x)`:x people in america. `A(x)`:x eat cheese burger. So, `∀A [P(x)->A(x)]` . But I am confused about the following one. Since, it's a phrase that's why I don't understand that what will be the domains and logic.

```
Every cloud has a silver lining
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first analysis is pretty good:

define:

$A(x)$: x eats cheese burgers

$P(x)$: x is an American

If you assume the domain is all Americans, then the statement 'all Americans eat cheese burgers' becomes $\forall x A(x)$

But if the domain is larger than that (say: all people in the world, or all objects in the world), then you have to use $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow A(x))$

For the second one, you have a similar choice:

1. The domain is all clouds
2. The domain is larger than all clouds (so again: maybe 'all object in the world')

Using:

$C(x)$: x is a cloud

$S(x)$: $x$ has a silver lining

You get $\forall x \: S(x)$ if you use the first option

And $\forall x (C(x) \rightarrow S(x))$ is you use the second option

Comment: you are helping me again and again :D nice explanation thanks

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar You're welcome!